# How to add a custom dialog with listview and search function in android fragment

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I want to create exactly same view shown below,

[image]

I used `showDialog` function to display dialog.

```
private void showDialog() {
    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    Fragment prev = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("dialog");
    if (prev != null) {
        ft.remove(prev);
    }
    ft.addToBackStack(null);

    // Create and show the dialog.
    DialogFragment newFragment = PopDialogFragment.newInstance();
    newFragment.show(ft, "dialog");
}
```

Help me to implement display listview and search listview function.

Edited code,

```
public class BookingFragment extends Fragment {

CardView cardFrom, cardTo;
TextView titleFromCity, titleToCity;
String[] nameOfCities;
    private Context context;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_bookings, container, false);
    titleFromCity = view.findViewById(R.id.textFromCity);
    titleToCity = view.findViewById(R.id.textToCity);
    cardFrom = view.findViewById(R.id.cardViewFrom);
    cardTo = view.findViewById(R.id.cardViewTo);
    cardFrom.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
            builder.setTitle("Choose City");

            nameOfCities = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.cities);

            builder.setItems(nameOfCities, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    titleFromCity.setText(nameOfCities[which]);

            });

            AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
            dialog.show();
        }
    });


    cardTo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            test();
        }
    });

    return view;
}

private void showDialog() {
    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    Fragment prev = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("dialog");
    if (prev != null) {
        ft.remove(prev);
    }
    ft.addToBackStack(null);

    DialogFragment newFragment = PropDialogFragment.newInstance();
    newFragment.show(ft, "dialog");
}

private void test() {
    final Dialog dialog_data = new Dialog(context);

    dialog_data.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    dialog_data.getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

    dialog_data.setContentView(R.layout.alert_label_editor);

    WindowManager.LayoutParams lp_number_picker = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
    Window window = dialog_data.getWindow();
    lp_number_picker.copyFrom(window.getAttributes());

    lp_number_picker.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    lp_number_picker.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;

    window.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    window.setAttributes(lp_number_picker);

    TextView alertdialog_textview = (TextView) dialog_data.findViewById(R.id.alertdialog_textview);
    alertdialog_textview.setText("Search City");
    alertdialog_textview.setHint("Search");

    Button dialog_cancel_btn = (Button) dialog_data.findViewById(R.id.dialog_cancel_btn);
    dialog_cancel_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            if(dialog_data != null)
            {
                dialog_data.dismiss();
                dialog_data.cancel();
            }

        }
    });

    EditText filterText = (EditText) dialog_data.findViewById(R.id.alertdialog_edittext);
    ListView alertdialog_Listview = (ListView) dialog_data.findViewById(R.id.alertdialog_Listview);
    alertdialog_Listview.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
    final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice, nameOfCities);
    alertdialog_Listview.setAdapter(adapter);
    alertdialog_Listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id)
        {


            if(dialog_data != null)
            {
                dialog_data.dismiss();
                dialog_data.cancel();
            }
        }
    });

    filterText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
    {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after)
        {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
        {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
        {
            adapter.getFilter().filter(s);
        }
    });

    dialog_data.show();
}
```

Comment: even the scroll bar should be same? have you prepared your view?
what else have you done till now?

Comment: no need to be same. Default scroll bar would be fine

Comment: and what exactly have you done? only the above code ?

Comment: no I have created popup layout. I already tried FragmentTransaction but it didn't work as i expected

Comment: Try implementing the listview and search bar. There are a number of help available on this implementation. Then if you encounter any problem let us know and share your implementation so we can be of help to you.

Comment: you can do the layout part i guess for functionality try Dialog Builder and then for editText use addTextChangedListener and if your listview is using a custom adapter override the method getFilter() of the adapter ....and here you go ...done. and use that filter. adapter.getFilter().filter(string); 
Done. If you want the layout do tell. I have created the same layout.

Comment: @Sahil I added my complete class here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace this line with new one

older one---> final Dialog dialog_data = new Dialog(context);

New one---> final Dialog dialog_data = new Dialog(getActivity());

Comment: @Cypher Please try this above solution

Answer (score 3):

[image]

```
    final Dialog dialog_data = new Dialog(context);

    dialog_data.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    dialog_data.getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

    dialog_data.setContentView(R.layout.custom_alertdialog);

    WindowManager.LayoutParams lp_number_picker = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
    Window window = dialog_data.getWindow();
    lp_number_picker.copyFrom(window.getAttributes());

    lp_number_picker.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    lp_number_picker.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;

    window.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    window.setAttributes(lp_number_picker);

    TextView alertdialog_textview = (TextView) dialog_data.findViewById(R.id.alertdialog_textview);
    alertdialog_textview.setText(selected_string);
    alertdialog_textview.setHint(selected_string);

    Button dialog_cancel_btn = (Button) dialog_data.findViewById(R.id.dialog_cancel_btn);
    dialog_cancel_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            if(dialog_data != null)
            {
                dialog_data.dismiss();
                dialog_data.cancel();
            }

        }
    });

    EditText filterText = (EditText) dialog_data.findViewById(R.id.alertdialog_edittext);
    ListView alertdialog_Listview = (ListView) dialog_data.findViewById(R.id.alertdialog_Listview);
    alertdialog_Listview.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
    final ArrayAdapter<String>  adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice, array_data);
    alertdialog_Listview.setAdapter(adapter);
    alertdialog_Listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id)
        {
            Utility.hideKeyboard(context,v);


 //data.setText(String.valueOf(a.getItemAtPosition(position)));


            if(dialog_data != null)
            {
                dialog_data.dismiss();
                dialog_data.cancel();
            }
        }
    });

    filterText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
    {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after)
        {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
        {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
        {
            adapter.getFilter().filter(s);
        }
    });

    dialog_data.show();

custom_alertdialog.xml

<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/alertdialog_linearlayout"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:background="@null">

<LinearLayout
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
  android:background="#FFFFFF">

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/alertdialog_textview"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="search"
      android:textColor="#000000"
      android:textSize="16sp"
      android:layout_marginTop="220dp"
      android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
      android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
      android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
      android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
      android:gravity="center"
      android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_launcher"
      android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_launcher"
      android:drawablePadding="10dp"/>

  <EditText
      android:id="@+id/alertdialog_edittext"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:ellipsize="end"
      android:textStyle="normal"
      android:textColorHint="#939598"
      android:textColor="#4b4f54"
      android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
      android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
      android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
      android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
      android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
      android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
      android:maxLines="1"
      android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
      android:gravity="start"
      android:inputType="text"
      android:theme="@style/alertdialog_edittextTheme"
      android:layout_gravity="start" />

  <ListView
      android:id="@+id/alertdialog_Listview"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
      android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
      android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
      android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
      android:choiceMode="singleChoice"/>

</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/dialog_cancel_btn"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:text="X"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/round_button"/>

 </RelativeLayout>

 round_button.xml


<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:innerRadius="0dp"
android:shape="oval"
android:thicknessRatio="1.9"
android:useLevel="false" >

<solid android:color="@android:color/white" />

<size android:width="100dp"
    android:height="100dp"/>

<stroke android:width="1dp"
    android:color="#000000"/>
```

Comment: @CypherX check the above solution

Comment: getting `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources$Theme android.content.Context.getTheme()' on a null object reference`

Comment: On which line your getting this NullPointerException.Please paste that line here.

Comment: on line `final Dialog dialog_data = new Dialog(context);`

Comment: can you please paste the updated code here please with activity or fragment class

Comment: added my complete fragment class.. please check

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153909/discussion-between-cypherx-and-yash786).