# Custom dialog with custom action on buttons

Tags: android

I'm thinking if it is possible to do a custom base class/method to create dialogs, but with custom actions loaded on live. I don't know if I've explained me so well.

If I have the next source:

```
public void showDialogCustom(String title, String content, String positiveText, String negativeText) {

        getBaseActivity().hideMaterialDialog();

        getBaseActivity().setDialog(new MaterialDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                .title(title)
                .content(content)
                .positiveText(positiveText)
                .negativeText(negativeText)
                .canceledOnTouchOutside(false)
                .cancelable(false)
                .onPositive(new MaterialDialog.SingleButtonCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(@NonNull MaterialDialog dialog, @NonNull DialogAction which) {
                        //SOME ACTION!!!

                    }
                })
                .onNegative(new MaterialDialog.SingleButtonCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(@NonNull MaterialDialog dialog, @NonNull DialogAction which) {
                        //SOME ACTION!!!
                    }
                })
                .show());
    }
```

I want to customize the action for positive or negative clicks. Call the class CustomDialog like, CustomDialog.showDialogCustom(params...) with the texts params and with the actions. Is this possible?

Thank you.

Comment: You can take a reference of this post:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46103090/how-to-add-a-custom-dialog-with-listview-and-search-function-in-android-fragment/46103240#46103240

Comment: You want a common dialog for the whole project. RIght?

Comment: It had nothing to do with the question... This type of answers does nothing.

Comment: Yes Sneha Sarkar, I want to have one dialog but with the action of the buttons customizables too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may help you. You can create a custom dialog layout as you want. And whenever you want to show any dialog just pass parameters according to your needs. In `DialogButtonListener` you will get the button click events for both positive and negative buttons.

```
public void displayDialog(final Context mContext, final String title, String msg, final String strPositiveBtn,
                              final String strNegativeBtn, final boolean isTitle, final boolean isNegativeBtn, final DialogButtonListener mDialogButtonListener) {
        if (mContext != null && !((Activity) mContext).isFinishing()) {
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(msg)) {
                msg = mContext.getString(R.string.alert_some_error);
            }
            final Dialog mDialog = new Dialog(mContext, R.style.StyleCommonDialog);
            final WindowManager.LayoutParams wlmp = mDialog.getWindow().getAttributes();
            wlmp.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
            wlmp.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
            wlmp.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
            mDialog.getWindow().setAttributes(wlmp);
            mDialog.setCancelable(true);
            mDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
            mDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            mDialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_common_dialog);

            final TextView tvTitle = mDialog.findViewById(R.id.common_dialog_tvTitle);
            final TextView tvMsg = mDialog.findViewById(R.id.common_dialog_tvMsg);
            final TextView btnPositive = mDialog.findViewById(R.id.common_dialog_btnPositive);
            final TextView btnNegative = mDialog.findViewById(R.id.common_dialog_btnNegative);

            tvTitle.setText(title.trim());
            tvMsg.setText(setFormattedHtmlString(msg.trim()));

            if (isTitle) {
                tvTitle.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                tvTitle.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            btnPositive.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListenerWrapper(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    mDialog.dismiss();
                    mDialogButtonListener.onPositiveButtonClicked();
                }
            }));

            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(strPositiveBtn.trim())) {
                btnPositive.setText(strPositiveBtn.trim());
            }

            if (isNegativeBtn) {
                btnNegative.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                btnNegative.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListenerWrapper(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        mDialog.dismiss();
                        mDialogButtonListener.onNegativeButtonClicked();
                    }
                }));
                if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(strNegativeBtn.trim())) {
                    btnNegative.setText(strNegativeBtn.trim());
                }
            } else {
                btnNegative.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            mDialog.show();
        }
    }
```

DialogButtonListener interface is like this:

```
public interface DialogButtonListener {
        void onPositiveButtonClicked();

        void onNegativeButtonClicked();
    }
```